# Tapestry support setup in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tapestry

I'd like to use Intellij IDEA 11 as IDE for a Tapestry web application but I don't know how to setup the whole thing in IDEA 11. It has a Tapestry plugin but there's no documentation on how it works.

Is there someone out there who use Tapestry with IDEA? Could you please post a tutorial for the setup?

It would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need a plugin, i've never found them to be much help. all you need is maven support and maybe html syntax highlighting on your .tml files (which i'm sure is configurable already).